# Extract content from HTML comments

Tags: php, html, comments

This is some HTML code

```
<!--start--> <h2>some content with any html tag</h2> <!--end-->
<!--start--> </h3> some other content with any html tag </h3><!--end-->
```

I need a PHP code to read the comments data. The tricky part is the comments are the same and I need both contents. Like H2 and H3.

I have the code but it gives just one. H3.

```
$html_file = file_get_contents($allfiles[0]); 

$string = '<!--start-->'.$html_file.'<!--end-->';
preg_match('/<!--start-->(.*)<!--end-->/', $string, $matches);
```

Comment: Try `preg_match_all()`

Comment: its not working either. Can you please write a code. Would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$html = <<<EOT
<!--start--> <h2>some content with any html tag</h2> <!--end-->
<!--start--> </h3> some other content with any html tag </h3><!--end-->
EOT;
   
// using preg_match_all
preg_match_all('/(<!--start-->)(.*)(<!--end-->)/', $html, $matches1);
$matches = $matches1[2];

foreach ($html of $matches) {
   echo $html;
}

// using explode
$htmla = explode("<!--start-->", $html);
foreach($htmla as $h) $matches2[] = trim(explode("<!--end-->", $h)[0]);
$matches =array_filter($matches2);
print_r($matches2);
```

Exmaple: https://www.tehplayground.com/ZCxwV8YWCQeePeFF

Both methods yeild:

```
Array
(
    [1] => <h2>some content with any html tag</h2>
    [2] => </h3> some other content with any html tag </h3>
)
```